# Bootstrap navbar doesn't work properly on mobile device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar, submenu

first time writing here.

I have one problem with my bootstrap nav when visiting site on mobile device.

I have navigation and I have like "gallery" and on click "Pictures" and "Video" as submenus to "gallery". The problem is when i click on MENU, it opens how it should, but when I click on "gallery" the "Pictures" and "Video" starts to show up but then whole menu collapses/closes. I can't even click on "Pictures" or "Videos".

I want behaviour like: I click MENU - it expands - I click "Gallery" - it expands - I click "video" then go to video page.
Current behaviour is like: I click MENU - it expands - I click "Gallery" - whole MENU collapses back / close.

Screenshot of NAV (desktop) as it works fine - http://prntscr.com/fugrrv

Screenshot of NAV (mobile) as it works fine - http://prntscr.com/fugs3j

I'll post my code so if you find out the problem please let me know, I lost all my nerves on this "little thing". 
Little mess with the code right now cuz I'm trying already any solution that I find... but no success.

I have jquery.min.js/css, bootstrap.min.js/css linked in head and footer

Sorry for bad english..

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"">
    <!-- navbar inverse - container fluid start -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">OPG Dumančić</a><span class="navbar-brand" id="brand-bull">&bull;</span></a><span class="navbar-brand" id="page-title"><?php echo "$pagetitle"; ?></span>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='index')?'active':'';?>">
                    <a href="/">Početna</a>
                </li>
                <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='onama')?'active':'';?>">
                    <a href="onama">O nama</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-dropdown nav-link">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Galerija &equiv;</a>
                    <ul class="navbar-inverse dropdown-menu nav-dropdown">
                        <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='galerija-slika')?'active':'';?>"><a id="aslike" href="galerija-slika">&rArr; Slike</a></li>
                        <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='galerija-videa')?'active':'';?>"><a id="avideo" href="galerija-videa">&rArr; Video</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='kontact')?'active':'';?>">
                    <a href="kontakt">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few small errors in it; an additional quotation mark, an additional closing anchor (`</a>`) and a closing unordered list that was omitted.  Correcting these issues and running the code seems to result in Bootstrap functioning as expected:

https://www.bootply.com/LnbYC1Ib1S

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">OPG Dumančić</a><span class="navbar-brand" id="brand-bull">&bull;</span><span class="navbar-brand" id="page-title"><?php echo "$pagetitle"; ?></span>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='index')?'active':'';?>"><a href="/">Početna</a></li>
        <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='onama')?'active':'';?>"><a href="onama">O nama</a></li>
        <li class="nav-dropdown nav-link">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link nav-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Galerija &equiv;</a>

            <ul class="navbar-inverse dropdown-menu nav-dropdown">
            <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='galerija-slika')?'active':'';?>"><a id="aslike" href="galerija-slika">&rArr; Slike</a></li>
            <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='galerija-videa')?'active':'';?>"><a id="avideo" href="galerija-videa">&rArr; Video</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="<?=(isset($menuid) && $menuid=='kontact')?'active':'';?>"><a href="kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You very much for reply. Beginners mistakes.. I corrected the errors as you said but somehow it works in fiddle you provided, but on mobile phone it doesn't? I get the same result as before. Gallery still collapses whole menu instead of expanding.. I triend coping your edited code still no progress... :/

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it has something to do with JS but I have managed to bypass this problem (for now).

Somehow when I remove class "navbar-collapse" from the div with the id "navbar-collapse" from above, everything works fine on mobile but every navlink dissapers on PC (only Brand is still displayed). So I used media query to display #navbar-collapse as block until it shrinks to "menu" button (cant just display:block cuz then it's always opened o mobile), seems to work for now. Thanks for reply Robert C!